# ngrok: do I need have a server in my computer to run it?

Tags: ngrok

I downloaded ngrok and I put in my website folder (example: documents/website).

I ran this command via command line: `./ngrok http 8888`

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online                                            
Version                       2.0.19/2.0.19                                     
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040 
Forwarding                    http://299954c1.ngrok.io -> localhost:8888
```

but I could not open the website and I got this:

`GET /favicon.ico               502 Bad Gateway

GET /                          502 Bad Gateway`

so I start see my ngrok just run if my MAMP its running like my apache and mysql on my localmachine tha is true?

so I turn on my MAMP on my mac and boom starts work perfect, my question is: my MAMP need to be on to my ngrok run?

Answer (score 1):

yes, I found out i need any server running in my computer like: wamp, mamp, python server, so like that my page will be online too. put the ngrok file in your server folder.